# MobileNet Keras tfrecord and tensorflow estimator...network does not improve accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train from scratch a mobile net model in order to recognize images of japanese character.

I'm feeding the net by some tfrecord files I created, and If I read the file they contain the data (images) I expect.

I have 64x64x1 images that I convert to 64x64x3 images before feeding to the network. And I have 956 classes.

After training the net for 8-10 hours with GPU (approx 100.000 iteration) the accuracy on validation set is always 0.

The loss of the training decreases and is approx to 0, but the loss on the evaluation data first grows and the is stable around an asimptotic value (i.e. 16).

I tried to leverage with tensorflow estimator in order to have clean code, and I'm using rmsprop as optimizer (I tried also adam)

I think there should be some macroscopic mistake in my code, but I cannot find it.

I would like to know also if I have to hot_one encoding labels before feeding the network or not, and If I can use also the label "0.....0" all zeros.

Any help is really appreciated.

Regards.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

import numpy as np
import sys
from PIL import Image
import shutil

def imgs_input_fn(filenames, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1, batch_size=1):
    def _parse_function(serialized):
        features = \
        {
            'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/channel': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
        # Parse the serialized data so we get a dict with our data.
        parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized,
                                                 features=features)
        # Get the image as raw bytes.
        image_shape = tf.stack([parsed_example['image/width'], parsed_example['image/height'], 3])
        image_raw = parsed_example['image/encoded']
        label = tf.cast(parsed_example['image/class/label'], tf.int32)
        #image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image_raw, 3)
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)

        #image = tf.image.resize_images(image, (224, 224))

        ## ADDED
        image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)

        num_classes = 956
        ## HOT ONE ENCODING
        d = dict(zip([input_name], [image])), tf.one_hot(label, num_classes)
        return d

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)
    # Parse the serialized data in the TFRecords files.
    # This returns TensorFlow tensors for the image and labels.
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    if perform_shuffle:
        # Randomizes input using a window of 256 elements (read into memory)
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=8192)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(repeat_count)  # Repeats dataset this # times
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)  # Batch size to use
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()




    path_tfrecords_train = [
        '/home/myuser/data_set/dump_train_00000-of-00006.tfrecord',
        '/home/myuser/data_set/dump_train_00001-of-00006.tfrecord',
        '/home/myuser/data_set/dump_train_00002-of-00006.tfrecord',
        '/home/myuser/data_set/dump_train_00003-of-00006.tfrecord',
        '/home/myuser/data_set/dump_train_00004-of-00006.tfrecord'
    ]

    path_tfrecords_test = [
        '/home/myuser/data_set/dump_validation_00000-of-00002.tfrecord',
        '/home/myuser/data_set/dump_validation_00001-of-00002.tfrecord',
    ]



def relu6(x):
    return tf.nn.relu6(x)

with tf.keras.utils.CustomObjectScope({'relu6': relu6}):
    model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(
                #input_shape=(128, 128, 3),
                #alpha=0.25,
                depth_multiplier=1,
                dropout=0.001,
                weights=None,
                input_tensor=None,
                pooling=None,
                classes=956,
                include_top=True
            )

    model.summary()

    input_name = model.input_names[0]
    model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy'],
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])

    model_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "model_metadata")
    os.makedirs(model_dir, exist_ok=True)

    estimator_model = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model,
                                                            model_dir=model_dir)


    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=lambda: imgs_input_fn(path_tfrecords_train,
                                        perform_shuffle=True,
                                        repeat_count=1,
                                        batch_size=64),
                                        max_steps=500)

    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda: imgs_input_fn(path_tfrecords_test,
                                         perform_shuffle=False,
                                         batch_size=1))

    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator_model, train_spec, eval_spec)


# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
model_json_file = os.path.join(model_dir, "model.json")
with open(model_json_file, "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model_weight_file = os.path.join(model_dir, "model.h5")
model.save(model_weight_file)
print("Saved model to disk")
```